# Why assign write and execute permissions to a group when executing web scripts?

Tags: linux, permissions

If I have a script that is to be executed by the `nobody` user, why is there a need to assign group read and execute permissions. For example in the article at http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml, it notes that the permission 755 should be assigned to scripts on a web server. I understand that the user `nobody` is treated as `others` and as the owner of the script I would like full permissions. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not clear on your question.  The script permissions define who can run, read, modify it.  If it is owned by `nobody` and the webserver is run as `nobody` (and assuming no suphp etc), then only `nobody` needs any permissions to the script in order for the webserver to run the script

Comment: well, accoring to that link, ""nobody" belongs to "others" group".  I didn't think "others" was a group, I'm not big on linux so don't know if that's right. But if so then I suppose you may need the same permissions on group and on others. that's what they've done..On a more sure point though,   5 is not write and execute permissions by the way, 5 is read and execute. I wonder if actually "others" is not part of any group, so one might ask, why not 705? perhaps you know or perhaps you were asking that too?

Comment: @Paul - What I meant was is `nobody` is a user that belongs to `others` or is `nobody` a user that also exists as a group? I understand that the web server is run as the user `nobody` so I would think that to read and execute the script, the permissions required would be 705 i.e. rwx for the user who own the file, no permissions for the group and r-x for others.

Comment: @barlop - Sorry, I wrote down `write` instead of `read` permissions. I have amended my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With linux permissions, `others` means "everyone else".  So lets say you have a file with permissions like this:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 peanut users 256 Jan 1 myscript
```

Ignoring the first -, we have `rwx` first, which are the `user` permissions.  The `user` is the account that owns the file, and is in the third column: `peanut`.  This user is permitted to read, write and execute the file.

Next we have `r-x` which are the `group` permissions, and the group in question is in the fourth column: `users`.  Anyone who is a member of this group is permitted to read and execute this file.  You can see group membership by doing:

```
$ grep users /etc/group
users:x:100:tom,dick,harry
```

This shows the group id `100` and anyone who is not a primary member of the group.  Primary members can be found by searching the passwd file for members - anyone who has `100` in the fourth column is a primary member:

```
 peanut:x:1000:100:peanut,,,:/home/peanut:/bin/bash
```

The last permissions are `--x` which are the `others` permission, or "everyone else" - ie, every one who isn't either the user or a member of the group.  This would include the user `nobody` if it exists, but also any other user.  So everyone else is permitted to execute this file.

Quite often, the webserver on linux is run under its own account, sometimes `nobody` sometimes `www-data` sometimes `httpd` sometimes `apache`.  Whatever the user is that runs the webserver daemon, if you want it to execute a script, then it needs permission to do so.  It is rare that you would make the webserver user the owner of the script or a member of the group that owns the script, so this only leaves the `others` permission to give it access.

An alternative approach for a site running multiple websites, is to create a user per site, then use suexec to say in the virtualhost definition which user should be used to execute scripts.  This way you don't need to give the webserver any explicit or implicit permission to the scripts.

Comment: So you seem to be saying that indeed one could say 705. Also, does execute permissions(1) include read permissions. since if one can execute a file, then one can read it. Even though when setting the execute bit alone, the read bit is not set.

Comment: @barlop Yes, a script needs to be readable in order to run it.  In fact, you don't need the execute bit set for a script to run it, you can just pass it to the interpreter like `python myscript`.  If you make it executable, and put the right shebang line at the beginning of the script, then you can execute it by name.  You usually don't need the execute bit set for a script run by a webserver as it will generally invoke an internal or external interpreter.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HN0kY4Pa  <-- 2 examples from cygwin. one is a script not readable but executable and executes.  another is a script that is readable not executable, and it executes even though not (Exlicitly at least) passed to bash

Comment: @barlop cygwin isn't linux.  Clearly you can read the file as you can `cat` it.  So while you don't have explicit read permissions from a cygwin perspective, windows is letting you read it without read and execute it without execute.

Comment: @Paul - Thanks Paul. As always your answers are in detail. A few questions arise though. How do I know the users that fall under the category of `others`? Why are primary group members kept separate from the `group` file?

Comment: `Others` means everyone else - literally.  If they have an account they are in `others`.  The primary group is in `/etc/passwd`, but I think it is for legacy reasons that there are two mechanisms for defining groups.  It was realised at some point that a single group in /etc/passwd wasn't enough to manage permissions effectively and so /etc/group came along.  I am guessing though.

Comment: @Paul - Okay so if I have a user called `Joe` and he belongs to the group `ABC` which has access to a file or directory `123`, I take it that `Joe` does not fall under `others`. Only users that do not belong to the group `ABC` would be treated as `others`. Is that right?

Comment: You look at it from the perspective of the file.  So if joe is not the user owner of the file, and not the in the group that owns the file, then he falls into the others category.  So "yes" in answer to your question, I just wanted to be clear(er).  Note that permissions are additive too, so if joe owns the file but the user permissions are nothing, yet the others permission is read-write, then joe gets read write.